# Deploy app to azure app services from VS 2015 broken since latest updates

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, webdeploy

I'm using azure app services to host a static web site (plain html + css + images) and 1-2 web applications (MVC 5 and Web API). I'm using the "shared" app plan. The web apps run in a virtual directory underneath the main web site. So the logical structure (end user perspective) is as follows:

```
mySite.azurewebsites.net: Static welcome page
    mySite.azurewebsites.net/webapp1: MVC 5 and HTML 5 web app
    mySite.azurewebsites.net/webapp2: MVC 5 and HTML 5 web app
```

A week ago, everything worked fine with following scenario:

- Create azure web app (app services app) "mySite.azurewebsites.net"
- In the azure portal, go to the app settings and add a virtual directoy

  Virtual path: "/webapp1", physical directory: "site\webapp1"
- Download the publishing profile for "mySite.azurewebsites.net" either from the azure portal or the cloud exporer in visual studio
- In VS, right click the web site project for "mySite.azurewebsites.net" and select "publish"
- In the "Publis web" dialog, choose "import" and import the previously downloaded publishing profile
- Publish "mySite.azurewebsites.net" => Works fine
- Publish "webapp1" as descripted in [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx)

  - In VS, right click the project "webapp1" (which should end up as "mySite.azurewebsites.net/webapp1"
  - In the "Publish web" dialog, choose "import" and import the previously downloaded publishing profile again. Add "/webapp1" to "site name" and "destination url"
  - Publish "mySite.azurewebsites.net/webapp1" => Works fine

As of yesterday (after updating VS 2015 community edition with latest updates), publishing "webapp1" to the virtual directory does not work anymore. First, VS displayed the error "can't find existing loaded project". After some research I found the work around to got to the "Azure App Service Activity" window in VS an click the little "Publish Web" icon. The publishing runs through and the browser automatically opens opens URL "mySite.azurewebsites.net/webapp1", it shows nothing (blank page). Chrome dev tools show the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (OK)". Sometimes the page displays "Error in CGI application...".

The kudu tools ("mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net") show following structure (same as last week when it worked):

```
site
  approot (code for webapp1, created automatically by the publishing process)
    packages
    runtimes
    src
    ...
  wwwroot
    index.html (my static welcome page)
    css
    img
    ...
  webapp1 (client files for webapp1: js, css...)
    css
    images
    ...
```

So I'd like two ask two questions:

- Is it still supported to publish web apps to virtual directories of an azure web app? It worked till about a week ago.
- When publishing to a virtual directory, as opposed to the mentioned MSDN-Blog, shouldn't I use the phyisical directory "site/webapp1/wwwroot" instead of just "site/webapp1" in order to get following structure:

```
site
  webapp1
    approot (the code for webapp1)
      packages
      runtimes
      src
      ...
    wwwroot (the client-files: css, js etc)
      css
      images
      ...
  wwwroot (the root of my static welcome page)
    index.html (my static welcome page)
    css
    img
    ...
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

Comment: if you publish normally instead of of to virtual directory does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, "normal" deployment works fine. It's just the virtual directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you publish using Web Deploy, the published code files go to "wwwroot" directory.
you can also add virtual directory paths in the Application Settings of the web app on the portal. 
 [image]

Comment: Yes, that's true, but deploying to a subsite or virtual directory does not wor. the basic idea is to have several apps underneath one website: "myWebsite" and "myWebsite/app1", "myWebsite/app2" etc. Thanks

Comment: you can add virtual directory paths in the Application Settings of the web app on the portal.